# CSS3 cover property-does it keeps the aspect ratio?

Tags: css

I am creating one website which uses CSS3 fullscreen gallery. This is my first time i am using CSS3 for fullscreen images, rather than JS.

The thing is that the background-size:cover property which i am using is not doing what i think it should be doing. I thought that by using cover, the image is resized by browser, but that it keeps it original aspect ratio, so that nothing is clipped, but this is not happening.

For example, if i am using 1500x900 image on a resolution 1366x768 the image is not scaled rightly, it covers everything, but it cuts off some of it, because the image provided is bigger than the resolution.

Here is the code i use for bg images:

```
   .image{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
 }
```

Also, here is the website test page: http://www.madebym.net/test/index.html
Just compare the thumbnails and the bigger images.

Thanks

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is `localhost`. Your website, sadly, is inaccessible.

Comment: There is some problem...the site is live on server, i will try to fix it ASAP

Comment: Your website redirects to a `127.0.0.1` address through JS.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i will fix it in two min tops.

Comment: Are you really asking for a property that does NOT keep the aspect ratio of the image but instead scales the width and height of the image independently so both covers the available room?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want **contain**

> contain, which specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.
>
> cover, which specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)

Comment: I know of contain, but it leaves black borders on each side of an image. I thought that cover would be doing an equivalent of jQuery image galleries, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**contain** and **cover** keeps the aspect ratio of the image correct, which means parts of it may be missing or parts of the area will be left uncovered (if the aspect ratio of the block don't happen to match the aspect ratio of the image exactly).  If you want the image to exactly fill the block regardless of aspect ratio, what you want is simply:

```
image-size: 100% 100%
```